# If a player doesn't own a gamepass, then prompt it via ScreenGUI not working?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a localscript for a **TextButton** so that when somebody clicks on it, the script **checks if they have the gamepass**. If they do, it will do a multitude of other things. **But**, if the player **doesn't** have the gamepass, then it will **prompt it to them.**

Here is the code for my localscript:

```lua
local ID = 42076468
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local MPS = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if MPS:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(plr.UserId,ID) then
        -- do stuff
    else
        MPS:PromptGamePassPurchase(plr.UserId,ID)
    end
end)
```

The problem is that it doesn't prompt the player, even when I remove my conditional statements. This localscript is inside of a TextButton, inside of a Frame, inside of a ScreenGUI.

Any help is deeply appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a simple mistake of calling [PromptGamePassPurchase(player, gamePassId)](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/MarketplaceService/PromptGamePassPurchase) the same way as [UserOwnsGamePassAsync(userId, gamePassid)](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/MarketplaceService/UserOwnsGamePassAsync).

`PromptGamePassPurchase` expects you to pass in a Player as the first argument, whereas `UserOwnsGamePassAsync` expects a userId. So all you gotta do is correct the first argument.

```
MPS:PromptGamePassPurchase(plr, ID)
```

Also, don't forget to define the callback for the [ProcessReceipt](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/callback/MarketplaceService/ProcessReceipt) event!